# supporting both form and json encoded bodys with FastAPI

Tags: python, http, fastapi

I've been using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) to create an HTTP based API.  It currently supports JSON encoded parameters, but I'd also like to support `form-urlencoded` (and ideally even `form-data`) parameters at the same URL.

Following on [Nikita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60670614/1358308) I can get separate urls working with:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Form, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyItem(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int] = None
    txt: str

    @classmethod
    def as_form(cls, id: Optional[int] = Form(None), txt: str = Form(...)) -> 'MyItem':
        return cls(id=id, txt=txt)

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/form")
async def form_endpoint(item: MyItem = Depends(MyItem.as_form)):
    print("got item =", repr(item))
    return "ok"

@app.post("/json")
async def json_endpoint(item: MyItem = Body(...)):
    print("got item =", repr(item))
    return "ok"
```

and I can test these using `curl` by doing:

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/form" -d 'txt=test'
```

and

```sh
curl -sS -X POST "http://localhost:8000/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"txt":"test"}'
```

It seems like it would be nicer to have a single URL that accepts both content-types and have the model parsed out appropriately.  But the above code currently fails with either:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","txt"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

or

```
{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

if I post to the "wrong" endpoint, e.g. form encoding posted to `/json`.

For bonus points; I'd also like to support `form-data` encoded parameters as it seems related (my `txt` can get rather long in practice), but might need to turn it into another question if it's sufficiently different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FastAPI can't route based on Content Type, you'd have to check that in the request and parse appropriately:

```py
@app.post('/')
async def route(req: Request) -> Response:
    if req.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        item = MyItem(** await req.json())
    elif req.headers['Content-Type'] == 'multipart/form-data':
        item = MyItem(** await req.form())
    elif req.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        item = MyItem(** await req.form())
    return Response(content=item.json())
```

There seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/990) on GitHub regarding this functionality