# Set description for query parameter in swagger doc using Pydantic model (FastAPI)

Tags: python, fastapi

This is continue to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468402/query-parameters-from-pydantic-model).

I have added a model to get query params to pydantic model

```
class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    x: str = Field(description="query x")
    y: str = Field(description="query y")
    z: str = Field(description="query z")


@app.get("/test-query-url/{test_id}")
async def get_by_query(test_id: int, query_params: QueryParams = Depends()):
    print(test_id)
    print(query_params.dict(by_alias=True))
    return True
```

it is working as expected but description(added in model) is not reflecting in swagger ui

[image]

But if same model is used for request body, then description is shown in swagger

[image]

Am I missing anything to get the description for QueryParams(model) in swagger ui?

Comment: I disagree with Arakkabal's answer, i was able to this, also OpenAPI Spec & Swagger allows this and query parameters has a description field [see](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters).So that means you should be doing this, because FastAPI is based on OpenAPI specification. I'll take a look at this again, later today.

Comment: thank you, kindly let me know if you find anything

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This is not possible with Pydantic models**

The workaround to get the desired result is to have a ***custom dependency class (or function)*** rather than the  Pydantic model

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


class CustomQueryParams:
    def __init__(
        self,
        foo: str = Query(..., description="Cool Description for foo"),
        bar: str = Query(..., description="Cool Description for bar"),
    ):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar


@app.get("/test-query/")
async def get_by_query(params: CustomQueryParams = Depends()):
    return params
```

Thus, you will have the doc as,

[image: screenshot]

---

#### References

1. [Validate GET parameters in FastAPI--(FastAPI GitHub)](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318) It seems like there is less interest in *extending the Pydantic model* to validate the GET parameters
2. [Classes as Dependencies--(FastAPI Doc)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/)

Comment: This would do. But wanted to have pydantic model

Comment: You can't do this with Pydantic. [ref this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318)

Comment: not sure why to use Query though, it has similar attributes as pydantic Field

Comment: `Query(...)` is used to generate the OpenAPI schema

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Query

@app.post("/route")
def some_api(
        self,
        query_param_1: float = Query(None, description="description goes here", ),
        query_param_2: float = Query(None, description="Param 2 does xyz"),
):
    
return "hello world"
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer for Pydantic V2 at least

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer refers to the use of custom dependencies using FastAPI [classes as dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1) to define the query parameters in bulk and while I think it works great, I feel the using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=dataclasses#module-dataclasses) would be better in this case and reduces the code duplication as the `__init__` will be generated automatically.

**Normal class as dependency**

```
class QueryParams:
    def __init__(self, 
    x:  Query(
            None, description="Arg1", example=10),
    y:  Query(
            None, description="Arg2", example=20)
    ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

While for lesser number of query params it would be just fine to do it this way but if the number of args is large as it was for me for one of my api endpoints, this quickly becomes cumbersome.

**Using dataclass as a dependency**

```
@dataclass
class QueryParams:
    x:  Query(None, description="Arg1", example=10)
    y:  Query(None, description="Arg2", example=20)
```

Plus you will also have added goodies of dataclasses if you need more complex functioanlities.

Comment: Like Pydantic-based model, this doesn't work with _path_ params; e.g: `stage: tp.Literal['add','delete'] = fa.Path(description='this is the stage')`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple working example on how combine Pydantic with FastAPI for query params:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import List
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

ROUTER = APIRouter()

class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    OPTION_ONE = "option_one"
    OPTION_TWO = "option_two"

class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    foo: List[str] = Field(Query(
        default_factory=list,
        description="List of foo parameters",
    ))
    bar: MyEnum = Field(Query(
        default=MyEnum.OPTION_ONE,
        description="Enum for bar parameters",
    ))

@ROUTER.get("/endpoint")
async def endpoint(params: QueryParams = Depends()):
    foobar = "something"  # Dummy response
    return {"foobar": foobar}
```

**Resulting Swagger Docs:**
[Swagger Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kk96.png)

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998227/how-to-define-query-parameters-using-pydantic-model-in-fastapi) solution also shows how to do this.

Comment: As a matter of fact though, "wrapping" the `Query` inside the `Field` function call does not quite work.  `pydantic.Field` actually has it's own `default`, `description` and `example` parameters, which work exactly as `fastapi.Query`.