# How to disable Authentication in FastAPI based on environment?

Tags: python, authorization, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a FastAPI application for which I enable `Authentication` by injecting a dependency function.

controller.py

```
router = APIRouter(
prefix="/v2/test",
tags=["helloWorld"],
dependencies=[Depends(api_key)],
responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
```

)

Authorzation.py

```
async def api_key(api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header_auth)):
if api_key_header != API_KEY:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid API Key",
    )
```

This works fine. However, I would like to **disable** the authentication based on environment. For instance, I would want to keep entering the authentication key in `localhost` environment.

Comment: I think that you can do it playing with the `.env` file then read it and on your Authorization.py put something like: `if os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT") == "development":`.

Comment: as I have already injected the dependency how will I by pass it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a subclass of [`APIKeyHeader`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/60ef67a66b1e0cadc2f4b4d6ea9f84baec8768f3/fastapi/security/api_key.py#L41) class and override the `__call__()` method to perform a check whether the request comes from a "safe" `client`, such as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, using `request.client.host`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689393/17865804). If so, you could set the `api_key` to application's `API_KEY` value, which would be returned and used by the `check_api_key()` dependency function to validate the `api_key`. In case there were multiple API keys, one could perform a check on the client's hostname/IP in both the `__call__()` and the `check_api_key()` functions, and raise an exception only if the client's IP is not in the `safe_clients` list.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, HTTPException
from starlette.status import HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
from fastapi.security.api_key import APIKeyHeader
from fastapi import Security
from typing import Optional

API_KEY = 'some-api-key'
API_KEY_NAME = 'X-API-KEY'
safe_clients = ['127.0.0.1']


class MyAPIKeyHeader(APIKeyHeader):
    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:
        if request.client.host in safe_clients:
            api_key = API_KEY
        else:
            api_key = request.headers.get(self.model.name)
            if not api_key:
                if self.auto_error:
                    raise HTTPException(
                        status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail='Not authenticated'
                    )
                else:
                    return None

        return api_key


api_key_header_auth = MyAPIKeyHeader(name=API_KEY_NAME)


async def check_api_key(request: Request, api_key: str = Security(api_key_header_auth)):
    if api_key != API_KEY:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Invalid API Key')

 
app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(check_api_key)])


@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return request.client.host
```

### Example (UPDATED)

The previous example could be simplified to the one below, which does not require overriding the `APIKeyHeader` class. You could instead set the `auto_error` flag to `False`, which would prevent `APIKeyHeader` from raising the pre-defined error in case the `api_key` is missing from the request, but rather let you handle it on your own in the `check_api_key()` function.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Security, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.security.api_key import APIKeyHeader


# List of valid API keys
API_KEYS = [
    'z77xQYZWROmI4fY4',
    'FXhO4i3bLA1WIsvR'
]
API_KEY_NAME = 'X-API-KEY'
safe_clients = ['127.0.0.1']
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name=API_KEY_NAME, auto_error=False)


async def check_api_key(request: Request, api_key: str = Security(api_key_header)):
    if api_key not in API_KEYS and request.client.host not in safe_clients:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Invalid or missing API Key')

 
app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(check_api_key)])


@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return request.client.host
```

## How to remove/hide the `Authorize` button from Swagger UI

The example provided above  will work as expected, that is, users whose their IP address is included in the `safe_clients` list won't be asked to provide an API key in order to issue requests to the API, regardless of the `Authorize` button being present in Swagger UI page when accessing the autodocs at `/docs`. If you still, however, would like to remove the `Authorize` button from the UI for `safe_clients`, you could have a custom middleware, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107848/17865804), in order to remove the `securitySchemes` component from the OpenAPI schema (in `/openapi.json`)—Swagger UI is actually based on OpenAPI Specification. This approach was inspired by the link mentioned earlier, as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71536816/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71958583/17865804). Please make sure to add the middleware after initialising your app in the example above (i.e., **after** `app = FastAPI(dependencies=...)`)

```py
from fastapi import Response

# ... rest of the code is the same as above

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(check_api_key)])


@app.middleware("http")
async def remove_auth_btn(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if request.url.path == '/openapi.json' and request.client.host in safe_clients:
        response_body = [section async for section in response.body_iterator]
        resp_str = response_body[0].decode()  # convert "response_body" bytes into string
        resp_dict = json.loads(resp_str)  # convert "resp_str" into dict
        del resp_dict['components']['securitySchemes']  # remove securitySchemes
        resp_str = json.dumps(resp_dict)  # convert "resp_dict" back to str
        return Response(content=resp_str, status_code=response.status_code, media_type=response.media_type)
    
    return response
```

Comment: This way I will be applying key through code for safe clients. I want to entirely remove the depends on authorization if the request comes from local host. So that we don't see an authorize button at all. Is this possible? to set decency in router based on safe clients?