# How to add request + additional attribute in depends method in Python API for authorization

Tags: python, fastapi, rbac

We are trying to authorize API based on role & permission of user for which there is method to check based on role of user & what he try to access

```
   
def check_permission(request: Request , permission:str=""):
  role=request.state.role
  if role not in cache:
        cache[role] = role_service.get_permission_by_role(role)
  permission_list=cache[role]
  index=permission_list.find(permission)
  return index > -1
```

& in API

```
@router.post('/banners',dependencies=[Depends(check_permission(permission=PermissionCodes.ADD_SITE_CONTENT))])
def add_banner(request:Request,file: UploadFile = File(...)):
```

But it is not passing request argument explicitly & throwing exception as TypeError: check_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

How can I pass request + permission_code in check_permission method ?

1. request: Request=Depends() tried which didnt worked
2. Mentioning explicitly in method argument

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: You might benefit from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160945/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterized dependency as shown in the documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/

In your code you are passing result of `check_permission` into Depends (this function will be executed before Depends). But Depends expects to get callable object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're *calling check_permission*, you're not adding the function itself as a dependency - just what it returns. You want to return a function from `check_permission`, which in turn has `request: Request` as one of its parameters:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


def check_permission(permission: str):
    def permission_checker(request: Request):
        print(request)
        return permission
        
    return permission_checker


@app.get("/", dependencies=[Depends(check_permission("admin"))])
async def read_items():
    return "foo"
```

Outputs:

```
INFO:     Application startup complete.
<starlette.requests.Request object at 0x000001FE03554FD0>
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54114 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```