# Skipping Authentication in FastAPI Based on POST request parameter

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi, auth0

I am currently working on a FastAPI project and facing a challenge in implementing a custom authenticator. My goal is to skip authentication based on the value of a specific parameter in the request body and return a hardcoded user ID when the condition is met.

Here's a simplified version of my main.py file which runs as:

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, status
from fastapi.openapi.models import OAuthFlows as OAuthFlowsModel
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer, SecurityScopes
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from jose import jwt
import uvicorn
import json

app = FastAPI()

# FastAPI OAuth2 configuration
fastapi_oauth2 = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl="your_authorization_url",
    tokenUrl="your_token_url",
)

# Mockup of auth0_jwks for the sake of example
auth0_jwks = "your_auth0_jwks"

# Mockup of SearchRequest and verify_token for the sake of example
class SearchRequest(BaseModel):
    query: str
    tenant: str

# Mockup of parse_request for the sake of example
async def parse_request(api_request: Request) -> SearchRequest:
    body = await api_request.body()
    body = json.loads(body.decode("utf-8"))
    return parse_obj_as(SearchRequest, body)

def verify_token(token: str = Depends(fastapi_oauth2)) -> dict:
    """
    Verifies Auth0 access token and attached permissions(scopes).
    Returns a dictionary of claims from the verified token.
    """
    if token == "mock_token":
        return {"sub": "mock_user_id"}

    try:
        # Add your token verification logic here, using your custom settings and keys
        jwt_claims = jwt.decode(token, key=auth0_jwks, audience="your_audience")
    except Exception as exc:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        ) from exc

    return jwt_claims

# Function causing the issue
def get_current_user_or_skip_auth(
    api_request: SearchRequest = Depends(parse_request),
    token: str | None = Depends(fastapi_oauth2),
) -> str:
    if api_request.tenant == "special_tenant":
        return f"{api_request.tenant}_user"

    jwt_claims = verify_token(token)  # Pass the token to verify_token
    if jwt_claims:
        return jwt_claims.get("sub")

    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )

# Basic POST request endpoint
@app.post("/process_request")
async def process_request(
    request: SearchRequest, user_id: str = Depends(get_current_user_or_skip_auth)
):
    """
    Process the incoming request.
    """
    return {"user_id": user_id, "request_data": request.dict()}

# Run the FastAPI application
if __name__ == "__main__":

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

**Issue:**

When I make a POST request with the tenant as "special_tenant" without a token, I expect the endpoint to skip the authentication process and return a JSON with the user_id as "special_tenant_user" and the request data. However, I am currently getting a "Not authenticated" error.

When I make a POST request with the tenant as "regular_tenant" with a mock token, I expect the endpoint to return a JSON with the user_id as "mock_user_id" and the request data. This is currently working as expected.

Here is an example of the issue:

1. Start the app with `uvicorn main:app --reload`
2. Open another terminal and run the following curl command to make a POST request with the tenant as "special_tenant" without a token:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/process_request" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"query\":\"test_query\",\"tenant\":\"special_tenant\"}"
```

3. The server returns a "Not authenticated" error.
4. But I expected it to return a JSON with the user_id as "special_tenant_user" and the request data.
5. Post request with a regular tenant works because it authenticates

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/process_request" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer mock_token" -d "{\"query\":\"test_query\",\"tenant\":\"regular_tenant\"}"
```

5. Returns this as expected

```
{"user_id":"mock_user_id","request_data":{"query":"test_query","tenant":"regular_tenant"}}%
```

**Question:**

What is the proper way to skip authentication and return a hardcoded user ID based on a specific parameter in the request body? Is this even possible to do while being safe in terms of OAuth standards?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160945/17865804) help you solve the issue?

Comment: Side notes: 1) You could use `request.json()` to get the request body parsed as JSON, instead of using `request.body()` and then parsing it yourself. 2) In Pydantic V2, [`parse_obj()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#changes-to-pydanticbasemodel) has been deprecated and replaced by [`model_validate()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#helper-functions)

Comment: You have to configure `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer` with `auto_error` set to `False` - otherwise a 401 error will be generated if the `Authorization` header is missing. If you set it to `False`, it'll instead return `None` (which you then need to check for before trying to validate the token).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved with a custom `AuthMiddleWare` class.
The tricky part was to experiment with different configurations to get around the way FastAPI passes variabels through its dependency injections using `Depends`. `Depends` usually makes the code simpler but also less customisable.

full `main.py` below

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, status
from fastapi.openapi.models import OAuthFlows as OAuthFlowsModel
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer, SecurityScopes
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from jose import jwt
import uvicorn
import json
from loguru import logger

app = FastAPI()

# FastAPI OAuth2 configuration
fastapi_oauth2 = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl="your_authorization_url",
    tokenUrl="your_token_url",
    auto_error=False, # when HTTP Authorization header is not available, instead of erroring out, the dependency result will be `None`.
)

# Mockup of auth0_jwks for the sake of example
auth0_jwks = "your_auth0_jwks"

# Mockup of SearchRequest and verify_token for the sake of example
class SearchRequest(BaseModel):
    query: str
    tenant: str

def verify_token(token: str = Depends(fastapi_oauth2)) -> dict:
    """
    Verifies Auth0 access token and attached permissions(scopes).
    Returns a dictionary of claims from the verified token.
    """
    if token == "mock_token":
        return {"sub": "mock_user_id"}

    try:
        # Add your token verification logic here, using your custom settings and keys
        jwt_claims = jwt.decode(token, key=auth0_jwks, audience="your_audience")
    except Exception as exc:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        ) from exc

    return jwt_claims

class AuthMiddleWare:
    """
    Middleware class for handling authentication in the API.
    """

    @staticmethod
    async def get_current_user(api_request: Request, token: str = Depends(fastapi_oauth2)) -> str:
        """
        Get user ID('sub' JWT claim) unless there is a custom tenant, in which
        case we skip auth and return a custom user.
        """
        body = await api_request.json()

        tenant_name = body.get("tenant", None)
        if tenant_name == "special_tenant":
            logger.info(f"returning {tenant_name}_user")
            return f"{tenant_name}_user"
        
        logger.info("tenant is generic, calling verify_token")
        jwt_claims = verify_token(token)
        if jwt_claims:
            return jwt_claims.get("sub")

        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )

# Basic POST request endpoint
@app.post("/process_request")
async def process_request(
    request: SearchRequest, user_id: str = Depends(AuthMiddleWare.get_current_user)
):
    """
    Process the incoming request.
    """
    return {"user_id": user_id, "request_data": request.dict()}

# Run the FastAPI application
if __name__ == "__main__":

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```