# Is there a way in FastAPI to access dependency output without calling it twice?

Tags: fastapi, auth0

My app is built with Auth0 and following this guide: https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-fastapi-server-with-auth0/. Now this is my app object:

```py
app = FastAPI(
    ...
    dependencies=[Security(auth.verify)],
)
```

Is it possible to retrieve the object returned by the `auth.verify` method from within my request? The state appears to be empty. The below code throws an `AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'user'`. I don't want to call the auth.verify twice by adding it to the list of explicit dependencies in the request. Also I want the authentication in one place and not at the top level and then redundantly at each endpoint I need this info again.

```py
@router.get("/")
async def get_user(request: Request):
    return request.state.user
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: @Chris This would help, but the Security doesn't take in a request, so there is no way for me to set I suppose.

Comment: Please check the link above again, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160945/17865804). [Depends() and Security()](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/dependencies/#security), in most cases, could be used interchangeably. You wouldn't have to pass `request` as an argument to the dependency function, but instead define it, i.e., `request: Request`, in the way you would normally do in an endpoint - FastAPI will take care of calling your dependency and passing `request`

Answer (score 0):

If the same dependency occurs several times, [FastAPI will still only call it once](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/sub-dependencies/#using-the-same-dependency-multiple-times). So just add it as a dependency in the endpoint and access it as usual.

Comment: But still I would need to include it twice in the code. So it is still redundant to specify. Is there no way to get the info? I am not opposed to adding the info to the request context manually.

Comment: I guess you could write your own dependency that uses `auth.verify` as a subdependency and adds it to the request object. Personally, I dislike that kind of "this property is magically added somewhere else" and prefer the explicitness of dependency injection, but to each their own.

Comment: @creyD If you need it in your controller, add it to your controller signature. If you don't, leave it out. The global dependency-definition is more of a fail-safe, and not one for retrieving / fetching the value. You'll have to tell your controller that the value is coming from _somewhere_, so having it in the signature makes it very easy to see what the value is and where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you M.O. and @MatsLindh I will probably then manually specify the dependency on each endpoint the data is required to be present.