# customized security in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using APIKeyHeader and Security decorators in order to protect my endpoints in FastAPI using some token.

The problem is that I want to have the security switchable, i.e. to deactivate it in test mode.

Is this possible?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Security
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader
app = FastAPI()
testMode: bool = 1
api_keys = [
    "my_api_key"
]
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key")

def get_api_key(api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header)) -> str:
    if api_key_header in api_keys or testMode == 1:
        return api_key_header
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid or missing API Key",
    )

@app.get("/protected")
def protected_route(api_key: str = Security(get_api_key)):
    return {"message": "Access granted!"}
```

Comment: even if testMode is set to 1, the endpoint brings a predefined error (status_code = 403, and not the one as intended in my code status_code=401).

Comment: the described error happens only if the token (X-API-Key) is left empty (not passed at all).
In case the token is passed (even with invalid value), then it executes the intended code (and the status_cod is 401 instead of 403).

Comment: Oh, I found it!
This is defined in the class APIKeyHeader inside api_key.py
I have edited the same class so it behaves like my intention.

How is it possible to inherit the same class in my main and override the __call__, so that I dont manipulate the api_key.py?

Comment: Do you want the test mode to be user-switchable or is it for unit testing?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160945/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about well fastApi but I tested and got followings. How about this?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Security
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader

app = FastAPI()
testMode: bool = True
# testMode: bool = False
api_keys = ["my_api_key"]
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key")


# def get_api_key(request_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header)) -> str:
def get_api_key(
    request_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header) if not testMode else None,
) -> str:
    print(f"request_key_header={request_key_header}")
    if request_key_header in api_keys or testMode == True:
        return request_key_header
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid or missing API Key",
    )


@app.get("/protected")
def protected_route(api_key: str = Security(get_api_key)):
    print(f"api_key={api_key}")
    return {"message": "Access granted!"}
```

If I change `testMode` to `True`, I'll get 'Access granted!' with request `curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/protected' -H "X-API-Key: wrong_key"`

If `testMode` is `False`, I'll get `{"detail":"Invalid or missing API Key"}` with same request.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it accepts invalid tokens (if testMode == True). But I wanted that it also accepts empty tokens too (if testMode == True)

Comment: This also works
`curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/protected' -H "X-API-Key: "`

But this does not works
`curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/protected'`

Answer (score 0):

The official way to disable security for tests is to override dependency before tests:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Security
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader

app = FastAPI()
testMode: bool = True
# testMode: bool = False
api_keys = ["my_api_key"]
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key")


def get_api_key(
    request_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header),
) -> str:
    print(f"request_key_header={request_key_header}")
    if request_key_header in api_keys:
        return request_key_header
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid or missing API Key",
    )

@app.get("/protected")
def protected_route(api_key: str = Security(get_api_key)):
    print(f"api_key={api_key}")
    return {"message": "Access granted!"}



# Define fake function
def fake_get_api_key() -> str:
    print("Return fake api_key")
    return "fake_key"

# Override dependency
app.dependency_overrides[get_api_key] = fake_get_api_key

# Now, fake_get_api_key will be called instead of get_api_key
```

I didn't run this code, but you should get the idea.

Read more about dependency overrides [in the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by inheriting the class APIKeyHeader and overriding its method **call**, so this code does what I wanted:

```
from typing import Optional#added
from starlette.requests import Request#added
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Security
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader
app = FastAPI()
testMode: bool = True
api_keys = [
    "my_api_key"
]
#here inherit the class and override its method
class MyAPIKeyHeader(APIKeyHeader):
    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:
        api_key = request.query_params.get(self.model.name)
        if not api_key and testMode == False:
            if self.auto_error:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=403, detail="Not authenticated, empty token"
                )
            else:
                return None
        return api_key

        
api_key_header = MyAPIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key")#added
#api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key")#replaced


def get_api_key(api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header)) -> str:
    if api_key_header in api_keys or testMode == True:
        return api_key_header
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid API Key",
    )

@app.get("/protected")
def protected_route(api_key: str = Security(get_api_key)):
    return {"message": "Access granted!"}
```