# Why DELETE method doesn't work in FastAPI?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-400

I want to pass 2 parameters into the handler, to validate it and to proceed work. There are two parameters: `id` of string type and the `date` of the DateTime in ISO8601 format. FastAPI always returns 400 error instead of at least return simply parameters back in json.

```
def convert_datetime_to_iso_8601_with_z_suffix(dt: datetime) -> str:
        return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')


class DeleteInModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    date: datetime

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: convert_datetime_to_iso_8601_with_z_suffix
        }

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        content=jsonable_encoder({'code': 400, 'message': 'Validation Failed'})
    )

@app.exception_handler(404)
async def existance_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestNotFoundException):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        content=jsonable_encoder({'code': 404, 'message': 'Item not found'})
    )

@app.delete('/delete/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def delete_import(date: DeleteInModel, id: str = Path()):

    return {'id': id, 'date': date}
```

Example of the request string:

```
localhost:8000/delete/элемент_1_5?date=2022-05-28T21:12:01.516Z
```

Comment: You have `{id}` as a path parameter, but it doesn't appear you are using one in your request. So fastapi can't find it, and returns 404

Comment: @crunker99 I slightly updated the code. The problem is 400 Validation Error also

Comment: I see. The issue is the endpoint expects DeleteInModel as the body in the request, but you have it as a query parameter. There is a fix for that though:
`date: DeleteInModel = Depends()`  - see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468402/query-parameters-from-pydantic-model

Comment: @crunker99 Thanks a lot! It works! Could you make an answer? P.S. I have absolutely no idea how should I figure it out by myself... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastApi allows using classes as a basis for query parameters: [classes-as-dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1)

In this case, you just need to change the parameter in `def delete_import` to:

`date: DeleteInModel = Depends(DeleteInModel)`,
or more simply

(see [shortcut](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#shortcut)
)
`date: DeleteInModel = Depends()`

so it expects `'?date='` in the url, otherwise it expects a json body matching the DeleteInModel as part of the request.