# How do I send list of dictionary as Body parameter together with Files in FastAPI?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multipartform-data, fastapi

In FastAPI to pass a `list` of dictionary, generally we will define a pydantic schema and will mention as:

```py
param: List[schema_model]
```

The issue I am facing is that **I have `files` to attach** to my request. I could not find a way to define a schema and File Upload in router function. For that I am defining all the parameters (request body) as `Body` parameters like below:

```py
@router.post("/", response_model=DataModelOut)
async def create_policy_details(request:Request,
    countryId: str = Body(...),
    policyDetails: List[dict] = Body(...),
    leaveTypeId: str = Body(...),
    branchIds: List[str] = Body(...),
    cityIds: List[str] = Body(...),
    files: List[UploadFile] = File(None)
    ):
```

When I send a request using `form-data` option of postman, it is showing `0:value is not a valid dict` for `policyDetails` parameter. I am sending `[{"name":"name1","department":"d1"}]`. It is saying `not a valid dict`, Even though I send valid dict. Can any one help me with this?

`DataModelOut` class:

```py
class DataModelOut(BaseModel):
    message: str = ""
    id: str = ""
    input_data: dict = None
    result: List[dict] = []
    statusCode: int
```

Comment: Hello samba can you also add the DataModelOut class?

Comment: I think DataModelOut will influence the response. I have an issue with request. i am added

Comment: I created request only with the policyDetails, it worked fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 8):

As per FastAPI [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#about-form-fields), **when including `Files` or `Form` parameters, "you can't also declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as `JSON`"**, as the request will have the body encoded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or `multipart/form-data`, if files are included) instead of `application/json`. Thus, you can't have both `Form` (and/or `File`) data together with `JSON` data. This is not a limitation of FastAPI, it's part of the `HTTP` protocol. Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) as well.

If you removed `files: List[UploadFile] = File()` parameter from your endpoint, you would see that a client's JSON request (using a valid JSON payload as request body) would go through without any errors, as the endpoint would expect an `application/json`-encoded request body (since you have declared each parameter in the endpoint with `Body` type), and not a `multipart/form-data`-encoded request body (which would be the case, if `UploadFile`/`File` parameter(s) were defined—**regardless of** whether you defined the rest of parameters as `Body` fields, they would be expected as `form-data` instead; in that case, `Form` type could be used as well, which is a class that inherits directly from `Body`—see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#define-form-parameters)). You could also confirm that using [OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#interactive-api-docs) at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs.

As for declaring a parameter such as `policyDetails: List[dict] = Body(...)` (or even `policyDetails: dict`), which is essentially expecting `JSON` data, you can't do that using `Form` fields, or `Body` fields along with `File` fields (in which case, they will again be interpreted as `Form` fields, as explained earlier). Hence, the error `value is not a valid dict` (even though it is not that informative), when attempting to send JSON data (i.e., a `dict` or `list` of `dict`) in a `Form` field, with the request's `Content-Type` header actually being set to `multipart/form-data` (in your case), or even `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, if only `form-data` were included.

### Solution

Therefore, your data, apart from `files`, could be sent as a stringified `JSON`, and on server side you could have a [custom pydantic class](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) that transforms the given `JSON` string into Python dictionary and validates it against the model, as described in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804). The `files` parameter should be defined **separately** from the model in your endpoint. Below is a working example demonstrating the aforementioned approach.

##### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body, status
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List
import json

app = FastAPI()

class DataModelOut(BaseModel):
    message: str = None
    id: str = None
    input_data: dict = None
    result: List[dict] = []
    statusCode: int
 
 
class DataModelIn(BaseModel):
    countryId: str
    policyDetails: List[dict]
    leaveTypeId: str
    branchIds: List[str]
    cityIds: List[str]
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate_to_json

    @classmethod
    def validate_to_json(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return cls(**json.loads(value))
        return value
    

@app.post('/', response_model=DataModelOut)
def create_policy_details(data: DataModelIn = Body(...), files: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    print('Files received: ', [f.filename for f in files])
    return {'input_data':data, 'statusCode': status.HTTP_201_CREATED}
```

##### Update

In Pydantic V2, a number of changes have been introduced - please take a look at the [Migration Guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/migration/) for more details, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804), regarding `@validator` decorators. The working example above has been updated (see below) to meet those changes.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body, status
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from typing import Optional, List
import json

app = FastAPI()


class DataModelOut(BaseModel):
    message: str = None
    id: str = None
    input_data: dict = None
    result: List[dict] = []
    statusCode: int
 
 
class DataModelIn(BaseModel):
    countryId: str
    policyDetails: List[dict]
    leaveTypeId: str
    branchIds: List[str]
    cityIds: List[str]

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def validate_to_json(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return cls(**json.loads(value))
        return value
    

@app.post('/', response_model=DataModelOut)
def create_policy_details(data: DataModelIn = Body(...), files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    print('Files received: ', [f.filename for f in files])
    return {'input_data': data.model_dump(), 'statusCode': status.HTTP_201_CREATED}
```

### Test the examples above

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) as well.

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
files = [('files', open('a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('b.txt', 'rb'))]
data = {'data' : '{"countryId": "US", "policyDetails":  [{"name":"name1","department":"d1"}], "leaveTypeId": "some_id", "branchIds": ["b1", "b2"], "cityIds": ["c1", "c2"]}'}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files=files) 
print(resp.json())
```

or, if you prefer this way:

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
files = [('files', open('a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('b.txt', 'rb'))]
data_dict = {"countryId": "US", "policyDetails":  [{"name":"name1","department":"d1"}], "leaveTypeId": "some_id", "branchIds": ["b1", "b2"], "cityIds": ["c1", "c2"]}
data = {'data': json.dumps(data_dict)}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files=files) 
print(resp.json())
```

You could also test the app using [OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#interactive-api-docs) at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs.

Finally, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77605018/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77279612/17865804) helpful, which provide related examples.

Comment: In my API, the files can be None or empty list. In your example, I can not send a request without any uploaded file. Do you have any idea? @Chris

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi The example above should work as expected - `files` are optional, and hence, one could send a request without having to include any `files` in it. When you declare optional parameters, one shouldn't include such parameters in their request specified with `null` or `None` - please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the problem belongs to the fastAPI docs. When I using curl in terminal, everything works fine.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should add a config class with `orm_mode` set to True in your Schema/Model class

```
    class DataModelOut(BaseModel):
       message: str = ""
       id: str = ""
       input_data: dict = None
       result: List[dict] = []
       statusCode: int
       
       class Config:
         orm_mode = True
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem directly comes from  **response_model**, and your returning values, let's say i have a app like this

```
class Example(BaseModel):
    name: str 
    
@app.post("/", response_model=Example)
async def example(value: int):
    return value
```

Now i'm sending a request to this

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Example
response
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

The error is same as yours. Even if i send the same parameters it will be raising the same error

```
class Example(BaseModel):
    name: int 
    other: int

@app.post("/", response_model=Example)
async def example(name: int, other: int):
    return name

Out:   value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

But if i declare the query parameter like this(best practice from [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/)) it 'll work just fine.

```
class Example(BaseModel):
    name: int 
    other: int

@app.post("/", response_model=Example)
async def example(ex: Example = Body(...)):
    return ex

Out: {
"name": 0,
"other": 0
}
```

In your case you can create two seperate models, `DataModelIn` and `DataModelOut`,

```
class DataModelOut(BaseModel):
    message: str = ""
    id: str = ""
    input_data: dict = None
    result: List[dict] = []
    statusCode: int
    
class DataModelIn(BaseModel):
    countryId: str 
    policyDetails: List[dict]
    leaveTypeId: str 
    branchIds: List[str]
    cityIds: List[str]


@app.post("/", response_model=DataModelOut)
async def create_policy_details(data: DataModelIn = Body(...)):
    return {"input_data":data,
            "statusCode":1}
```

Now i'm sending a request to this

```
Out: {
  "message": "",
  "id": "",
  "input_data": {
    "countryId": "30",
    "policyDetails": [
      {
        "some": "details"
      }
    ],
    "leaveTypeId": "string",
    "branchIds": [
      "string"
    ],
    "cityIds": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "result": [],
  "statusCode": 1
}
```

It works like a charm. You can also use `response_model_exclude_unset=True` parameter to discard `message` and `id` from response,also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014056/how-to-get-specific-responses-with-fastapi/63014988#63014988) out