# How to post dictionary data type in FastAPI Request Forms? Error : "msg": "value is not a valid dict", "type": "type_error.dict"

Tags: python, fastapi

My POST request using FastAPI's Swagger docs is using:

```
Request Body | application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I am trying to post:

1. "list" of "dict" using request form - error Code:422
2. Only "dict" using request form - error Code:422
3. without "dict" - It works

```
@menu.post("/add-menu")
async def addmenu(
    ItemName: str = Form(...),
    ItemShortDesc: str = Form(...),
    ItemPrice: str = Form(...),
    ItemCategory: list = Form(...),
    ItemStatus: str = Form(...),
    ItemChoices: list[dict[str,str]] = Form(...)):
    
    return ItemChoices
```

[image: FastAPI Swagger Screenshot]

I got the following error:

```
Code 422 | Error: Unprocessable Entity

{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "ItemChoices",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I use "dict" or "list" of "dict" in FastAPI request form?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439821/17865804).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send list of dictionary as Body parameter in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110848/how-do-i-send-list-of-dictionary-as-body-parameter-in-fastapi)