# Problem about axios post request and fastAPI

Tags: database, axios, frontend, backend, fastapi

I try to send json data from frontend to backend to use mysql, frontend use node.js and backend use fastAPI.
Since I found the request module from npm was deprecated, I use axios to send my post request.
But When the data send from axios to fastAPI, the uvicorn server raise 405 error. I try to add header `content-type: application/json`, but the response is same. I write a request.py try to send post request to fastAPI and it is success. I think the problem is in my axios request, but I don't know how to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StWWF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n7iI.png)

I want to know how to use both axios and fastAPI to build my signup system

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096718/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023536/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77279612/17865804)