# Getting error on the pydantic models : Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to create the pydantic model for the post Api but i am getting the following error:

```
Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from
```

Could anyone please help me regarding this?

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import UploadFile, File, Form, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Types(BaseModel):
    categoryid: str = Field()
    categoryname: str = Field()
    subcategoryid: str = Field()
    subcategoryname: str = Field()

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
        populate_by_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = False


class Availability(BaseModel):
    quantity: int = Form(...)
    size: str = Form(...)
    price: str = Form(...)

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
        populate_by_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = False


class ProductUnits(BaseModel):
    color: str = Form(...)
    image: str = Form(...)
    # availability: List[Availability] = Depends()


class Product(BaseModel):
    # productname: Optional[str] = None
    # minorder: Optional[int] = None
    # producttype: Types = Depends()
    # productdetails: Optional[str] = None
    productunits: List[ProductUnits]
    # shippingtime: Optional[str] = None
    # cod: Optional[bool] = None
    # codminimumamt: Optional[int] = None
    # returnpolicy: Optional[str] = None
    productimages: list[UploadFile] = File(...)
```

**Router**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, status, Depends

from src.products.models import Product
from src.utils.statuscode import statuscode

productrouter = APIRouter()


@productrouter.post("/", response_description="Create a products", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    )
async def create_product(request: Request, product: Product = Depends()):
    print(product)
    return statuscode(status=True, message='Product added Successfully')
```

**Error Track**

```
    {
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "model_attributes_type",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "productunits",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from",
      "input": "{\r\n  \"color\": \"string\",\r\n  \"image\": \"string\"\r\n}",
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/model_attributes_type"
    }
  ]
}
```

I had tried to change the typing values and base model many more but i able achieve the expected output

Please help me understand whats the issue causing that error in the pydantic when i try to run that api

Comment: Can you please add a full traceback of an appearing error?

Comment: Hi @puf added the error track

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439821/17865804) as well.

Comment: Hi @Chris I had seen your answer but in place dict i want my model in it