# Why do I get an "Unprocessable Entity" error while uploading an image with FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to upload an image but FastAPI is coming back with an error I can't figure out.

If I leave out the "`file: UploadFile = File(...)`" from the function definition, it works correctly. But when I add the `file` to the function definition, then it throws the error.

Here is the complete code.

```
@router.post('/', response_model=schemas.PostItem, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create(request: schemas.Item, file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    new_item = models.Item(
        name=request.name,
        price=request.price,
        user_id=1,
    )
    print(file.filename)
    db.add(new_item)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_item)
    return new_item
```

The `Item` Pydantic model is just

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
```

The error is:
Code 422    Error: Unprocessable Entity

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "request",
        "name"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "request",
        "price"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to post the _exact_ error message and response. Also, how are you sending the POST request? How are you uploading the file?

Comment: I am sending it using the SwaggerUI. So I click in the SwaggerUI file browser and select the image and upload. If I leave the request: ItemShow and the ItemShow from the route it works. SO I think I cannot have both the request: schemas.Item and file: UploadFile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your route is expecting 2 types of request body:

- `request: schemas.Item`

  - This is expecting POSTing an `application/json` body
  - See the [Request Body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) section of the FastAPI docs: "*Read the body of the request as JSON*"
- `file: UploadFile = File(...)`

  - This is expecting POSTing a `multipart/form-data`
  - See the [Request Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) section of the FastAPI docs: "***FastAPI** will make sure to read that data from the right place **instead of JSON**. ...when the form includes files, it is encoded as `multipart/form-data`*"

That will *not* work as that breaks not just FastAPI, but general HTTP protocols. FastAPI mentions this in [a warning](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#what-is-form-data) when using `File`:

> You can declare multiple `File` and `Form` parameters in a path operation, but **you can't also declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as JSON**, as the request will have the body encoded using `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`.
>
> This is not a limitation of **FastAPI**, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

The common solutions, as discussed in [Posting a File and Associated Data to a RESTful WebService preferably as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083702/2745495), is to either:

1. Break the API into 2 POST requests: 1 for the file, 1 for the metadata
2. Send it all in 1 `multipart/form-data`

Fortunately, FastAPI supports solution 2, combining both your `Item` model and uploading a file into 1 `multipart/form-data`. See the section on [Request Forms and Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/):

> Use `File` and `Form` together when you need to receive data and files in the same request.

Here's your modified route (I removed `db` as that's irrelevant to the problem):

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float

class PostItem(BaseModel):
    name: str

@router.post('/', response_model=PostItem, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create(
    # Here we expect parameters for each field of the model
    name: str = Form(...),
    price: float = Form(...),
    # Here we expect an uploaded file
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
):
    new_item = Item(name=name, price=price)
    print(new_item)
    print(file.filename)
    return new_item
```

The Swagger docs present it as 1 form

[image: swagger UI with form]

...and you should be able now to send both `Item` params and the file in one request.

If you don't like splitting your `Item` model into separate parameters (it would *indeed* be annoying for models with many fields), see this Q&A on [fastapi form data with pydantic model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60127234/2745495).

Here's the modified code where `Item` is changed to `ItemForm` to support accepting its fields as `Form` values instead of JSON:

```
class ItemForm(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float

    @classmethod
    def as_form(cls, name: str = Form(...), price: float = Form(...)) -> 'ItemForm':
        return cls(name=name, price=price)

class PostItem(BaseModel):
    name: str

@router.post('/', response_model=PostItem, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create(
    item: ItemForm = Depends(ItemForm.as_form),
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
):
    new_item = Item(name=item.name, price=item.price)
    print(new_item)
    print(file.filename)
    return new_item
```

The Swagger UI should still be the same (all the `Item` fields and the file upload all in one form).

For this:

> If I leave out the "`file: UploadFile = File(...)`" from the function definition, it works correctly

It's not important to focus on this, but it worked because removing `File` turned the expected request body back to an `application/json` type, so the JSON body would work.

Finally, as a side note, I strongly suggest *NOT* using `request` as a parameter name for your route. Aside from being vague (everything is a request), it could conflict with FastAPI's `request: Request` parameter when [using the Request object directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/).

Comment: Well this is an incredibly instructive answer. By the way I read all the time about splitting the request into the body and the file into two different requests. This is strange as most of the web work I have done an image is typically part of a request along with other values like name price etc.

Comment: I have one more comment. FastAPI is good but the error messages needs to be more expressive. I had encounter errors where I have no clues on what's going on. If you can throw some lights into how you interpret this error to reach the conclusion that I was doing all this wrong. In other words, to teach me/others your mental process to figure this out, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I noticed the price: str = Form(...), instead of float which is the right pydantic type. Is this an error?

Comment: @dianesis Yes, the price was a typo from copy-pasting without checking. It should be float in all the sample codes. Updated my answer.

Comment: @dianesis [1/2] For the 422 fastapi/pydantic error, I regularly get it when I'm either _passing_ the request wrong or _receiving_ the request wrong. I started with trying 1 route with just `item: Item` and 1 route with just `file: UploadFile...`, just to confirm they work normally as-is. Then, when it didn't work together, I [accessed the `Request` object directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/) to see the actual content-type and body of the request.

Comment: @dianesis [2/2] I checked `request.headers['content-type']` and saw that it was `multipart/form-data`. That gave me a hint that it won't get parsed properly into the Pydantic model, which accepts a dict (so the body should be in JSON). Then I re-read the FastAPI docs on the uploading files, and saw that warning about mixing JSON and Form in 1 request. (In hindsight, re-reading the docs first would have solved the problem much more quickly.)