# I need to send files and data through FastAPI. I'm trying to send requests but couldn't get it to work

Tags: python, request, rest, fastapi

I need to send files and data through FastAPI. I'm trying to send requests but couldn't get it to work

for example :

**server:**

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File
from pydantic import BaseModel


app = FastAPI()


class Data(BaseModel):
    test1: str = None
    test2: str = None
    test3: str = None


@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_file(
    data: Data,
    image: bytes = File(...),
):
    return {"postdata": len(image),
            "data": data.camera,
            }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

**client:**

```py
import requests
import cv2
import json
image = cv2.imread('/marti.jpg')
data2 = cv2.imencode(".jpg", image)[1]


payload = {"test1": "value_1", "test2": "value_2", "test3": "value_3"}
files = {
    'image': ('a.jpg', data2.tobytes(), 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '0'})
}

res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/uploadfile/",
                    files=files, data=payload)
print(res.content)
print(res.status_code, res.json())
```

**the error i got:**

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

---

- If I remove the 'files' from the request, it works.
- If I remove the 'data' from the request, it works.

---

**What are your suggestions in the face of this situation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `Data` in JSON body.

If you want to do it you should do:

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_file(
    test1: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    test2: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    test3: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    image: bytes = File(...),
):
    # Stuff here ...
```

**PS:** [[How to use pydantic model with form data]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127234/how-to-use-a-pydantic-model-with-form-data-in-fastapi#answer-60670614)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. See documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#what-is-form-data):

> You can declare multiple `File` and `Form` parameters in a path operation, but you can't also declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as JSON, as the request will have the body encoded using `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`.
>
> This is not a limitation of FastAPI, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

This is typically either resolved by expecting a `Form` as opposed to `json` (see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106597/1305461)), or by having two independent endpoints; one that uploads the photo and returns a matching ID, and another that leverages that ID to send the `json` data to.