# Pydantic params validation with file upload

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying upload user data with file. I wanna do something like this, validate user data and attach file

```
class User(BaseModel):
    user: str
    name: str

@router.post("/upload")
async def create_upload_file(data: User, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(data)
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

but it doesn't work
Error: Unprocessable Entity
Response body:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "data"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if i do separate ulr all work:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    user: str
    name: str

@router.post("/d")
async def create(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.filename}

@router.post("/")
def main(user: User):
    return user
```

How to combine all together?

Comment: Related topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request

Answer (score 2):

[You can't](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#about-form-fields) declare `Body` fields that you expect to receive as `JSON` along with `Form` fields, as the request will have the body encoded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or `multipart/form-data`, if files are included), instead of `application/json`.

You can either use `Form(...)` fields, [`Dependencies`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) with Pydantic models, or send a `JSON` string using a `Form` field and then parse it, as described in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have them at the same time, since pydantic models validate `json` body but file uploads is sent in `form-data`.

So they can't be used together.

If you want to do it you should do a trick.

Please check out this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127234/how-to-use-a-pydantic-model-with-form-data-in-fastapi) to know how to use pydantic models in form data.