# How FastAPI manages WFT Forms?

Tags: python, fastapi, wtforms

I am migrating from Flask to FastAPI and it is not clear to me how FastAPI manages WTF Forms.

I would like to use forms in Classes. However, I don't know if there is a correct way to do it in FastAPI, and if not what is the recommended solution to manage forms easily.

Here is a code example:

```
from fastapi import  Form

from wtforms import RadioField,SubmitField,SelectField, StringField,PasswordField, BooleanField

from wtforms.validators import Length, Email, InputRequired,EqualTo, DataRequired

class SignUpForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1,100),Email()])
    
    password = ...
    confirm_password = ...
```

Is it possible to handle Forms in this way in FastAPI?

FastAPI has already [a page explaining Forms in general](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/), but I didn't find any source explaining how to use it in a Class.

Any source to understand how FastAPI manages forms exactly is welcome.

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127234/how-to-use-a-pydantic-model-with-form-data-in-fastapi?

Comment: This is useful thanks, but maybe there is some clearer doc. The example you've mentioned seem a bit complex to me (maybe there is no choice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, the best library to use WTF Forms with FastAPI is starlette-wtf.

See: https://pypi.org/project/WTForms/

> Starlette-WTF integrates with Starlette and the FastAPI framework,
> based on the features of Flask-WTF.

```
$ pip install starlette starlette-wtf jinja2 uvicorn
```

Here is the code to do that:

```
from starlette_wtf import StarletteForm
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo
from wtforms.widgets import PasswordInput


class CreateAccountForm(StarletteForm):
    email = TextField(
        'Email address',
        validators=[
            DataRequired('Please enter your email address'),
            Email()
        ]
    )

    password = PasswordField(
        'Password',
        widget=PasswordInput(hide_value=False),
        validators=[
            DataRequired('Please enter your password'),
            EqualTo('password_confirm', message='Passwords must match')
        ]
    )

    password_confirm = PasswordField(
        'Confirm Password',
        widget=PasswordInput(hide_value=False),
        validators=[
            DataRequired('Please confirm your password')
        ]
    )
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/muicss/starlette-wtf).