Pydantic V2 model field_validation is not executed with Form Data in Fastapi 0.111.0
For Form data, I defined class as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60670614/6189499. Using pydantic v2, pydantic model is defined as
@as_form
class Test(BaseModel):
    param1: str
    c: bool = False
    
    @field_validator('c',mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def convert_to_bool(cls, v):
        print("hello inside bool")
        if isinstance(v, str):
            if v.lower() in {'true', 'True'}:
                return True
            elif v.lower() in {'false', 'False'}:
                return False
        return v

from fastapi import Depends, Form
@router.post('/me')
async def me(request: Request, form: Test = Depends(Test.as_form)):
    return form

Sending formdata, 'c' from basemodel is always string and field_validation is not executed. How to casting that string value 'c' to boolean? In pydantic v1, that string value c became boolean nothing to do but issued in pydanticv2
I tried this
@as_form
class Test(BaseModel):
    param1: str
    c: string= "False"

    @field_validator('c',mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def convert_to_bool(cls, v):
        print("hello inside bool")
        if isinstance(v, str):
            if v.lower() in {'true', 'True'}:
                return True
            elif v.lower() in {'false', 'False'}:
                return False
        return v

This also doesn't execute validation check.
EDIT
import inspect
from typing import Type

from fastapi import Form
from pydantic import BaseModel


def as_form(cls: Type[BaseModel]):
    new_parameters = []

    for field_name, field in cls.model_fields.items():

        field_default = Form(...)
        new_parameters.append(
            inspect.Parameter(
                field_name,
                inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY,
                default=Form(field.default) if not field.is_required() else field_default,
                annotation=inspect.Parameter.empty,
            )
        )

    async def as_form_func(**data):
        return cls.model_construct(**data)

    sig = inspect.signature(as_form_func)
    sig = sig.replace(parameters=new_parameters)
    as_form_func.__signature__ = sig
    setattr(cls, 'as_form', as_form_func)
    return cls

The above as_form is working except for field_validation execution. Pyndatic model field_validation works for BaseModel is not decorated with as_form. How to fix the issue in as_form?

Did you test out the other as_form decorators that have been adapter to Pydantic v2 in the question you linked? I think this is more a problem with the suggested as_form decorator and not with Pydantic, so you probably want to debug / fix that instead.

@MatsLindh Yeap, the issue might be in as_form decorator as field validation is working for other basemodel which don't have as_form. But couldn't fix the issue in as_form decorator.

Did you try the updated suggestions in the thread you linked? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113651/137650 https://stackoverflow.com/a/77188913/137650

@MatsLindh It worked
